# dynamic reconfigure accross multiple packages

Tags: ros, dynamixel-motor, ros-indigo, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using multiple packages for my application such as ,`dynamixel_motor`, `hokuyo_node`, `laser_geometry` and then my own package which subscribes the topics published by other packages. Now, based on some situation I want to change the extreme position limits of dynamixel servo. I want to do it from other package (say for example from within `laser_geomtery` based on pointcloud data I want to control servo's upper and lower position limits). I saw `dynamic_reconfigure` is a way to deal with such things. But I am confused if the same can be done across multiple packages. If yes, then how? By the way, I am writing my package in `c++` whereas, dynamixel_motor is written in `python`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284794/dynamic-reconfigure-accross-multiple-packages/) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think this is the answer to your question but I'll leave this answer here in case searches with similar keywords come across it:

I wrote a script called [dr2dr.py](https://github.com/lucasw/dynamic_reconfigure_tools/blob/master/dynamic_reconfigure_tools/scripts/dr2dr.py) that is meant to allow selecting individual controls from other dynamic reconfigure servers and combining them into a single server.   If server 1 had controls A, B, & C and server 2 had controls D, E, & F a new server 3 could be configured that has controls A & F for example.  Behind the scenes changing one of those controls on the front-end server 3 would result in interaction with the appropriate back-end reconfigure servers 1 and 2.

I haven't used it in a while a didn't leave a good demo behind (only [this](https://github.com/lucasw/vimjay/blob/master/config/stop_motion_dr.yaml)), so if it is of interest I can see if it works, fix it if it doesn't, and make a simple example.

In your case hokuyo_node has a dynamic reconfigure server, so the above might be useful, but I don't see a cfg in dynamixel_motor, you would have to add that functionality.  I didn't look at it closely but if there are other interfaces (like topics or services) that allow changing joint limits within dynamixel motor then you could write a dynamic reconfigure server for your own package that uses the alternate interface behind the scenes.  You can also manually have your reconfigure server call other reconfigure servers without dr2dr, that's just for some limited use cases.

If dynamixel motor only can be configured once at launch time then you are back in the position of having to modify it to make live changes possible.

From your description it isn't clear if your main node needs a reconfigure server, it is going to configure other nodes based on processing it does and not real time user control?

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on 2018-03-08**:
Thanks for the answer.
My main node has message_filter callback for `hokuyo_node` and servo. Within that callback, I call `laser_geometry` and I want to reconfigure the servo position limits from there within `laser_geometry`.

**Comment by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on 2018-03-08**:
I found another package `dynamixel-workbench` which does not have any cfg but seems to have some services which could be used for configuring it dynamically. Please have a look if you can manage time.

**Comment by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on 2018-03-08**:
and yes, I want to configure other node based on the processing which happens in real time. But I don't want any GUI based real time user control.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-03-08**:
If you don't need a gui then no need to give your own package dynamic reconfigure server.  It looks like dynamixel-workbench has position limits that can be set via services, so your callback could call those services.  Just look up ros C++ service client if that isn't familiar.

**Comment by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on 2018-03-29**:
Hey, I was able to create a separate message for the service in dynamxiel_workbench package and called it from my own package and everything worked flawlessly.

Thanks,